# Android TextView change <a> background color

Tags: android, textview

I want to change background color of a link in textview which was created using following code:

```
String htmlStr = "Click here: <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">SO</a>";
Spanned htmlSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlStr, this, null);
txtView.setText( htmlSpanned );
```

I used font tag but it didn't work.

Comment: what API are you using? make sure the API supports all the features you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using some css codes
The font tag can't change the background color of html links,
Try this code:

```
String htmlStr = "Click here: <a style='background-color:#00ff00' href=\'http://stackoverflow.com\'>SO</a>";
Spanned htmlSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlStr, this, null);
txtView.setText( htmlSpanned );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String htmlStr = "Click here: ";
String link = "<font color='blue'><a href=\'http://stackoverflow.com\'>SO</a></font>";
Spanned htmlSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlStr + link, this, null);
txtView.setText( htmlSpanned );
```

You can use the font tag to add color. Also can do something like:

```
int сolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.label_color);
String сolorString = String.format("%X", labelColor).substring(2);
Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font color=\"#%s\">text</font>", сolorString),
```

This grabs a color resource and strips it of the alpha channel value. Useful if you want to use a particular color else where in your project